# Find what ImageView is being dragged

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I am making a checkers game and using UIPanGestureRecognizer to drag an ImageView. I am trying to find what ImageView is being dragged across the screen so I can find what team it is on and if it is a king so I know if a move is legal.

```
    func pieceMoved(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer){

    if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended {
        tapEnd = gesture.location(in: self.view)
        print(tapBegin)
        print(tapEnd)
        checkBounds(begin: tapBegin, end: tapEnd)
    }else if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began{
        tapBegin = gesture.location(in: self.view)
    }
}

@objc func myPanAction(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)

    if let myView = recognizer.view {
        myView.center = CGPoint(x: myView.center.x + translation.x, y: myView.center.y + translation.y)
    }
    pieceMoved(gesture: recognizer)
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), in: self.view)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`UIView` has a tag property (an Int) that you can use for whatever purpose you want.  You could give each a unique number that you could check in your pan action.

If you want to do more, subclassing UIImageView and adding a property is pretty straightforward.